# Кастомный ID для таблицы Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

На собеседовании меня спросили: сделайте ID - идентификатор валюты, который возвращает метод (пример: R01010)
Но я ничего не понял. Что значит "возвращает метод"? Как подобное реализовыается?

Comment: Я тоже ничего не понял. Если про кастомный первичный ключ, то делается в миграции, `$table->primary('rub_id');` https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#available-index-types . Если про модель, там есть `public $incrementing = false; и $primaryKey = 'rub_id';` https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#primary-keys. Ну и еще в Модели можно определить название PK через `getKeyName()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю имелось ввиду что то на подобии этого

```
class MyModel extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{
    public function getIdAttribute()
    {
      return 'R' . $this->attributes['id'];
    }
}
```

Comment: А как добавить именно четырехзначный код? Как я понял, если я буду сейчас добавлять записи, то они пойду по возрастанию.

Comment: `echo sprintf("%'05d\n", 123);` не?